# Magento 2: Fatal error: Call to a member function getUsername() on null in

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, header, console

While developing in Magento 2 after a while i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUsername() on null in /home/magento2/domains/../public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml on line 32
```

I think it is after about 10 ~ 15 minutes. I need to relogin to proceed. What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class in admin controller.

Instead extend from `\Magento\Backend\App\Action class`, so it will redirect you to login page instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. It is also staying logged in for a longer time. I didn't got logged out since the fix (yet).

Comment: Btw, how did you know this was the problem. In other words, how did I had to solve this on my own? Did I mis a clue?

Comment: in M2, there is different class for backend , where magento check session. You can also use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action but here magento doesn't validate session.